# change id AUTO_INCREMENT from 1 to 0000..... in phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

hello i have an column with name id and its (int , 11 , AUTO_INCREMENT, prymary key)
and every time i register new user the id is added automatically as 1 or 2 ...
i want to change the id numbers from 1,2,3 to 0000000001 , 0000000002 ......

Comment: Leave them as numbers.  Why would you want to prepend zeros?

Comment: because im making directory's named according to the id number and its necessary for me to be 0000000001.....

Comment: Turn 1 into 000000001 after you pull it out of the database. I think primary keys are required to be numeric, though You could probably fake it with triggers or stored procedures if you needed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was curious with the lpad thing, not sure if it's a function that's ready with access or some database server. Anyway, here is how I pad it

```
select RIGHT('0000000000' + cast(ID AS NVARCHAR(100)),10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format it using a query:

```
 select lpad(id, '0', 10)
```